# Rails: def create does not add data to table using Rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, model-view-controller

I want to add data to table through rest api with url: `localhost:3000/api/v1/shoppinglists#create?grocery=fruits`

I have created a model already, my controller is located under `api/v1/shoppinglists_controller.rb` and the code for that is:

**shoppinglists_controller.rb:**

```
module Api
    module V1

        class ShoppinglistsController < ApplicationController

            def index
                shop = Shoppinglist.all
                render json: shop.to_json
            end

            def create
                @tst = Shoppinglist.create(grocery: params[:grocery])
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get '/shoppinglists' => 'shoppinglists#index'
      post '/shoppinglists' => 'shoppinglists#create'
    end
  end
end
```

**Model-migration: shoppinglist.rb:**

```
class CreateShoppinglists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shoppinglists do |t|
      t.integer :shopid
      t.string :type
      t.string :grocery
      t.string :status

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

By default, def index gets triggered but when I do: `localhost:3000/api/v1/shoppinglist#create?grocery=fruits` then I check on commandline, I still see:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/shoppinglists" for ::1 at 2015-06-23 23:59:06 -0400
Processing by Api::V1::ShoppinglistsController#index as HTML
  Shoppinglist Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shoppinglists".* FROM "shoppinglists"
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

and my table is empty. There are 2 problems:

1. I dont understand why still `index` is getting triggered and how can I make `def create` to actually insert value in grocery column through rest api.

   - [Solved] I used a client called `Postman` to solve this problem but still facing problem (2) as all null values are entered in my table and not the one being entered through url. My command line logs now say [logs]
2. Once it gets triggered then is my code right for "create" def?

   - [Solved] Issue was with the way I was sending values through post. I had to add values to form-data tab (key,val) in Postman instead of through url for it to work

[logs]

```
Started POST "/api/v1/shoppinglists" for ::1 at 2015-06-24 01:03:44 -0400
Processing by Api::V1::ShoppinglistsController#create as */*
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "shoppinglists" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-06-24 05:03:44.714945"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-24 05:03:44.714945"]]
   (8.2ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 8.7ms)
```

Comment: you need post method

Comment: I have a post method declared in my routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Create action requires a POST request and when you visit localhost:3000/api/v1/shoppinglist#create?grocery=fruits in a browser, **it sends a GET request instead of a POST request, treating it as a URI and hence triggering index action.*** To send a POST request you can use [`CURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/) command in terminal or [`httparty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'-H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shoppinglists -d {"grocery": "fruits"}
```

*where **-H refers to the headers set in request and -X is for changing default GET verb and -d is for the data that you want to send.*** For details refer to [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: it helped me in my 1st part of the question but now even though it does get triggered I am unable to add value like this:
localhost:3000/api/v1/shoppinglists#create?grocery=fruits 
Its updating all null values in my table.

Comment: @fscore 2nd part depends on other things. How are you sending data values in request? Are those values even received by the server? if they are then what attributes you have in table, do you have any validation errors? Have you permit those attributes for mass assignment?

Comment: sent this request: localhost:3000/api/v1/shoppinglists#create?grocery=fruits.. what logs do you like to see?
updated the command line log

Comment: @fscore looking at logs, params[:grocery] is nil so your record is being created with null values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81355/discussion-between-fscore-and-mandeep).

Comment: @fscore sorry i'm upto something so can't come on chat, take a look at https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests#body

Comment: thanks for your help! Solved that. Issue was the way I was sending values through post. I had to add values to formdata tab in postman instead of through url for it to work

Comment: Any tutorial recommendations for Ruby on Rails? Rest stuff or in general?

Comment: @fscore rail guides is still the best resource, you can find everything you need  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/